# Derived categories of filtered modules

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, derived-functors, model-categories, filtered-modules

For a ${\mathbb Z}$-filtered ring ${\mathbb k}$ one can consider the category ${\mathbb k}\text{-filt}$ of ${\mathbb Z}$-filtered ${\mathbb k}$-modules, equipped with the exact structure which declares a sequence $X\to Y\to Z$ to be exact if $0\to X_k\to Y_k\to Z_k\to 0$ is exact for all $k$.

As for any exact category, this gives rise to a derived category $\textbf{D}({\mathbb k}\text{-filt})$ of complexes of ${\mathbb Z}$-filtered ${\mathbb k}$-modules.

> ***Questions:***
>
> 1. Is $\textbf{D}(A\text{-filt})$ a compactly or at least well-generated triangulated category?
> 2. What is known about model categorical enhancements for $\textbf{D}({\mathbb k}\text{-filt})$?

In particular I would like to understand if, given a morphism of ${\mathbb Z}$-filtered rings ${\mathbb k}^{\prime}\to{\mathbb k}$, there is a left adjoint to the forgetful functor $\textbf{D}({\mathbb k}\text{-filt})\to\textbf{D}({\mathbb k}^{\prime}\text{-filt})$, and, if yes, how it looks like explicitly.

Generally I'm interested in any source treating derived categories of filtered modules; so far I have only found literature on derived categories of exact categories in general, not focussing on this special case, however.

Comment: If you take instead the derived category of the category $\mathcal{Q}$ of $\mathbb{k}$-filt quotiented out by torsion objects, and $\mathbb{k}$ satisfies the hypotheses for Serre's equivalence, then $\mathbf{D}(\mathcal{Q})$ is equivalent to $\mathbf{D}(\operatorname{qcoh} X)$ where $X = \operatorname{Proj} \mathbb{k}$, and $\mathbf{D}(\operatorname{qcoh} X)$ is compactly generated if $X$ is qcqs by Thm. 3.1.1 in http://www.ams.org/distribution/mmj/vol3-1-2003/bondal-vandenbergh.pdf

Answer (score 1):

A model-categorical enhancement of D(k-filt) is constructed in [arXiv:1602.01515](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01515),
see Corollary 3.58 there.
It also shows that this model category is combinatorial and compactly generated, as requested.

A morphism f: k→k' of **Z**-filtered rings induces a Quillen adjunction,
as shown in Theorem 5.5 there.
In fact, if f is a graded equivalence, then the Quillen adjunction is a Quillen equivalence, as mentioned there.

Explicitly, the (derived) left adjoint to the forgetful functor
from filtered k'-modules to filtered k-modules can be explicitly
described as the (derived) filtered tensor product (i.e.,
the tensor product in the monoidal category of filtered objects)
with k' (as a k-module).

Comment: Dmitri, thank you very much for your answer, this recent work sounds very promising!